# Turing Machine - Learning Skills

Tags: turing-machines

It took me the whole month to solve this problem, as I got it from the book one of exercise, and I'd love to know how to write this in a turing machine; I would really love to learn this. Please could anyone offer a help?

> Consider the last two letters of your login (if both letters are the same, please pick
>   the next letter in the Latin alphabet as your second symbol). Write a Turing Machine
>   that will recognise the language Stretch(x+1). This is the language of all strings that
>   contain a continuous string of occurrences of the two letters, followed by ‘*’,
>   followed by another string of letters with x+1 occurrences of the each letter where
>   there was a single occurrence in the first string of letters. Here, x = 1. Input to the machine is non-null strings of a, b, *. As an
>   example, where the letters are ‘a’ and ‘b’ (and x=1) aba*aabbaa, bb*bbbb and
>   baab*bbaaaabb are in the language, but abb*abbb is not. You may assume that you
>   have subroutines for writing 0 in the first cell and deleting the rest of the tape and for
>   writing 1 in the first cell and deleting the rest of the tape.

I would totally appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: You should pick a different character other than '*', that totally confused me.  Or explicitly say its not an RE.

Comment: It's clearly homework.  Look at the pleads for 'send meh teh codez'

Comment: Good point. Too bad TM proofs are just so darn fun.

Comment: @Jason: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Sabrina: What have you tried?  What specific point is holding you back?  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Roger - Thank you, I wasn't aware of that decision. I appreciate the link.

Answer (score 3):

Use a stack for each unique letter (two stacks, in your examples).  This isn't formally written or anything, but all you have to do is provide an algorithm to prove a TM can solve the problem.

```
F1:
FOREACH letter DO
  IF letter = '*' THEN F2
  ELSE push letter twice onto its respective stack

F2:
FOREACH letter DO
  IF tape is empty THEN F3
  IF respective stack is empty THEN *fail state*
  ELSE pop respective stack

F3:
IF both stacks are empty THEN *accept state*
ELSE *fail state*
```

Get the idea? TM proofs are fun.

*EDIT*: In response to your other posts, if you don't understand how to build a TM proof you'll need to do some reading about proofs in general.  I would suggest [Michael Sipser's Intro to Theory of Computing](http://www.google.com/#q=theory+of+computation+sipser&hl=en&prmd=ivs&source=univ&tbs=shop:1&tbo=u&ei=oNvWTLjdNJO4sQPnj_2NCw&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=image&resnum=3&sqi=2&ved=0CDIQzAMwAg&biw=1215&bih=780&fp=2827f4b43f03484d).  After you shell out an arm and a leg for that text, you can turn to page 137 to learn all about TMs.